# Is there any literature that compares the candle-power to the candela?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, specific-reference, si-units

I am unable to find anything in the literature to back up the claim that appears all over the internet that:

```
The modern candlepower now equates directly to the number of candelas.
```

Can anyone please suggest something in the scientific literature to back up this statement?

If this is not the correct stack exchange for this question, please suggest a better one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this paper is what you are looking for? http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5323103&tag=1

A quote:

> The form of primary standard of light (Fig. 1) now in force internationally consists of a black-body (or cavity) radiator held at the temperature of freezing platinum (2042° K). The corresponding unit of luminous intensity is the 'can- dela' (cd). By definition, the brightness or luminance of the radiator is 60cd/cm2. The figure 60 was chosen to ensure con- tinuity, so that, within limits of experimental error at the various relevant dates, an intensity of 1 cd is the same as the older international candle, which in turn was approximately equal to the intensity of the earliest standard sperm candle.

Comment: This definition was valid from 1948 to 1979. The new definition is 1 cd = 1/683 W/sr of monochromatic light at 540 THz.

Comment: hehehehe, freezing platinum